# Finding maxima of a log and a linear term

Tags: derivatives, inequality, logarithms, maxima-minima

I am supposed to study the function $$f(x)=x\cdot \ln(x+2)$$ To find the maxima and minima, I am supposed to set its first derivative $$f'(x)=\ln(x+2) + \frac{x}{x+2} \ge 0$$

However, I am unsure of how to solve this. Is there an easy (that I could have reasonably been taught given that I am in my last year of high school), that I am overlooking, to solve this, or are there any alternative methods/shortcuts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To find the critical points, you are supposed to set $f'(x)=0$. You can now perform the [First Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First-derivative_test) or the [Second Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second-derivative_test_(single_variable)) on the value(s) that you get.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this other method, but it still leaves the problem open of finding the roots of the function: I can't really think of a way to solve the equation $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: That looks like a transcendental equation.

Comment: If you are familiar with the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) then this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve $f'(x)=0$ you have to use [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)  or numerical methods like Newtons method. I am solving via Lambert W function,

$$\ln(x+2) + \frac{x}{x+2} = 0{ \implies\ln y +\frac{y-2}y=0\quad(\text{Where, $y=x+2$})\\
\implies y(\ln y+1)=2\\
\implies y\ln(ey)=2\\
\implies \ln(ey)=\frac{2}y\\
\implies 2e=\frac{2}y e^{2/y}\\
\implies W(2e)=\frac{2}y\\
\implies y=\frac{2}{W(2e)}\\
\implies x=\frac{2}{W(2e)}-2\approx-0.5453}$$

For high school student I recommend to solve the equation by graph, plot $f(x)=\ln(x+2)$ and $g(x)=-\frac{x}{x+2}$ and find the intersection point.
[image: Graphical solution]